# Android BLE cant find devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to run Google sample BluetoothLeGatt and it simply doesn't find any devices when i press the Scan option.

The onLeScan method on callback is never called.

Am i missing something?

- I tried in many devices, from 18 to 21 versions.
- Didn't change any line of code, just imported the sample on Android Studio.
- The method startLeScan returns true.
- I have already tried to increase the scan timeout value (SCAN_PERIOD).

Log (if any device was found, its mac address should be shown here)

```
 8515-8515/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt D/BluetoothAdapter? stopLeScan()
 8515-8515/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt D/BluetoothAdapter? startLeScan(): null
 8515-8528/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt D/BluetoothAdapter? onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
 8515-8515/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt D/BluetoothAdapter? stopLeScan()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your device?

Comment: Galaxy S4, Nexus 4 and loads of Sony devices (i work in a team that makes apps for Sony).

Comment: No, nothing strange, i will add the log to the question..

Comment: `startLeScan(): null` Whats this? What `NULL` refers to?

Comment: @user370305 Well, looking at the source code, when i callstartLeScan(LeScanCallback), a call to startLeScan(UUID[], LeScanCallback) is made, passing null as the first argument. This null in the log refers to the first argument.